# i am getting an error in my face recognition code while excuting it in pycharm, have also tried executing it on terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, terminal, pycharm

My face recognition code is getting and error. The error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Harsh/Desktop/python codes/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-xeqjxthj\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1689: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'

[ WARN:0] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-xeqjxthj\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (434) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

the code is as follows:

```
import cv2


face_cascade = \
cv2.CascadeClassifier('/C:/User/Harsh/Downloads/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')

eye_cascade = \
cv2.CascadeClassifier('/C:/User/Harsh/Downloads/haarcascade_eye.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while 1:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    if ret is True:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    else:
            continue

    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

    for(x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+h]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+h]
        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
        for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:
            cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (ex, ey), (ex+ew), (ex+ew, ey+eh), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xFf

    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

That error means that your *xml* file could not be found.

You got some typos here:

```
face_cascade =
cv2.CascadeClassifier('/C:/User/Harsh/Downloads/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')

eye_cascade =
cv2.CascadeClassifier('/C:/User/Harsh/Downloads/haarcascade_eye.xml')
```

Notice the slash (/) at the beginning of the path. Correct that and it should work.